# AngularJS isolate scope ng-model validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, isolate-scope

I would like to use the built in form validation provided by AngularJS for custom component directive. However it doesn't work. When validation is failed modelValue and viewValue set to '' empty string.
I lost all my typing...

script.js

```
angular.module("myModule", [])
     .directive("customIsolateDirective", function () {
        return {
            restrict : "A",
            scope : {
                ngModel : "="
            },
            // Replace original template
            template : '<div ng-form="form"><input ng-model="ngModel" ng-maxlength="10" ng-class="{ error : form.$invalid }"></div>',
            replace : true
        };
    });
};
```

In DOM HTML

```
<input type"text" ng-model="model" custom-isolate-directive>
```

Can I use ng-model in the DOM element?
Because I want to use ng-model directive without custom isolate directive too.

The goal is I want to each form component directives has it's own isolated scope and validating it's own scope independent parent scope. If I change `<input ng-model="model">` element's ng-model directive to `<input model="model">` it works fine. My question is can I use **ng-model** attribute to two way bind child isolated scope's **ng-model** with same name?
Because maybe I want to change my component directives dynamically.

Here is the problem that I created in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/muaNnjrItAl2rzpXvkdx?p=preview)

Comment: Can you explain elaborately? Can't understand what is the actual problem.

Comment: Hi, go to my Plunker and type something in the input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this strange behavior is because the model property that you are binding the input to becomes undefined when the max length is exceeded.  All you need to do to fix this is set the allowInvalid model option flag to true on the input.

```
<div ng-form="form">
<p>Please try to type something in the input box. <em>(max-length: 11)</em></p>
<input ng-model="ngModel" ng-maxlength="11" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" ng-class="{ error : form.$invalid }">
<p style="margin-top : 0;">ngModel length : {{ ngModel.length }}</p>
<pre>{{ form | json }}</pre>
```

[Here is an updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WLks9x1fQOg4cL2b0rWt?p=preview)

Comment: I didn't know about `ng-model-options`. I learned **getterSetter** option and fixed the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting my very first answer.  I'm glad you were able to find another way.